# NOT IN query not working, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]

The first part of the query before `not in` runs and gives me a list of 100 records.  The second query runs and gives me a list of 75 records.  The query I'm trying to write using `not in` is to get the records that are in one result set, but not the other.  The error I get is `incorrect syntax near the word not`.

```
SELECT distinct  Patient.patientid
FROM Patient INNER JOIN
 patientICD ON Patient.patientid = patientICD.patientid AND Patient.admissiondate = patientICD.admissiondate AND 
                      Patient.dischargedate = patientICD.dischargedate INNER JOIN
                      tblICD ON patientICD.primarycode = tblICD.ICD_ID
WHERE     (tblICD.descrip LIKE N'%diabetes%') and  not in
(
SELECT    distinct Patient.patientid
FROM         Patient INNER JOIN
 patientICD ON Patient.patientid = patientICD.patientid AND Patient.admissiondate = patientICD.admissiondate AND 
                      Patient.dischargedate = patientICD.dischargedate INNER JOIN
                      tblICD ON patientICD.primarycode = tblICD.ICD_ID
WHERE     (tblICD.icd_id LIKE N'25000')
)
```

Is it ever allowed to write a query with `expression AND NOT IN (select query`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify what field is not in the second query

```
and Patient.patientid not in
```

Comment: ugh, I can't stand overlooking something so menial.  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to write this?

```
WHERE     (tblICD.descrip LIKE N'%diabetes%') and Patient.patientid not in
```

**UPDATE**

Would it be possible to rewrite the entire thing as this?

```
SELECT distinct  Patient.patientid
FROM Patient INNER JOIN
 patientICD ON Patient.patientid = patientICD.patientid AND Patient.admissiondate = patientICD.admissiondate AND 
                      Patient.dischargedate = patientICD.dischargedate INNER JOIN
                      tblICD ON patientICD.primarycode = tblICD.ICD_ID
WHERE tblICD.descrip LIKE N'%diabetes%' AND tblICD.icd_id NOT LIKE N'25000'
```

Comment: `Would it be possible to rewrite the entire thing as this?` No. It are different detail records; selected using different attributes.

Comment: Please let me know if you do happen to try it that way, and whether or not it works.  Something that will definitely work - you can encase all of your JOINs into a single CTE statement, and keep the WHERE exclusion clauses outside of the CTE.  Then, you'll only scan the tables once.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did. See my answer. But basically the two tblICD*tblICD subqueries refer to different tuple-sets: one should exist, the other one should not exist. One is for diabetes, the other for disease number 25000(whatever that might be)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a field before NOT.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify the column that the `not in` is looking at. So according to your script I think you would want `and Patient.patientid not in`

Answer (score 1):

Purely stylistic: you can "squeeze out" the patientICD*tblICD product, and put it into a CTE, and reference that twice, like: (untested)

```
WITH zzz AS (
        SELECT pic.patientid , pic.admissiondate , pic.dischargedate
        , tab.ICD_ID , tab.descrip
        FROM patientICD pic
        JOIN tblICD tab ON pic.primarycode = tab.ICD_ID
        )
SELECT DISTINCT p.patientid
FROM  Patient p
JOIN zzz one ON one.patientid = p.patientid
             AND one.admissiondate = p.admissiondate 
             AND one.dischargedate = p.dischargedate 
WHERE one.descrip LIKE N'%diabetes%'
AND p.patientid NOT IN (
        SELECT two.patientid 
        FROM zzz two
        WHERE two.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
        AND two.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
        AND two.icd_id LIKE N'25000'
        );
```

NOTE: I don't like the `LIKE N'25000'`. I think an exact match would be fine. And the icd_id-field should be numeric, probably. And the {admissiondate,dischargedate} pair should be modelled out, too; possibly by using a diagnosis_id or incident_id.

Comment: CTEs are something that I'm just starting to learn about; I've only been playing with SQL Server for a couple months now.  I always like learning how to do something a new way though. `distinct`, not distint :).  what do you mean by 'squeeze out?'