# SQL issue: one to many relationship and EAV model

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening guys,
I'm a newbie to web programming and I need your help to solve a problem inherent to SQL query.
The database engine I'm using is MySQL and I access it via PHP, here I'll explain a simplified version of my database, just to fix ideas. 
Let's suppose to work with a database containing three tables: `teams`, `teams_information`, `attributes`. More precisely:

1) `teams` is a table containing some basic information about italian football teams (soccer, not american football :D), it is formed by three fields: 'id' (`int, primary key)`, 'name' (varchar, team name), `nickname` (`Varchar`, team nickname);

2) `attributes` is a table containing a list of possible information about a football team, such as `city` (the city where team plays its home match), `captain` (team captain's fullname), `f_number` (number of fans) and so on. This table is formed by three fields: id `(int, primary key)`, `attribute_name` (`varchar`, an identifier for the attribute), `attribute_desc` (text, an explanation of the meaning of attribute). Each record of this table represents a single possible attribute of a football team;

3) `teams_information` is a table where some information, about teams listed in `team` table, are available. This table contains three fields: id (`int`, primary key), `team_id` (`int`, a foreign key which identifies a team), `attribute_id` (`int`, a foreign key which identifies one of the attributes listed in `attributes` table), `attribute_value` (`varchar`, the value of the attribute). Each record represents a single attribute of a single team. In general, different teams will have a different number of information, so for some teams a large number of attributes will be available while for other teams only a small number of attributes will be available.

Note that relation between `teams` and `teams_information` is one to many and the same relation exists between `attributes` and `teams_information`

Well, given this model my purpose is to realize a grid (maybe with ExtJS 4.1) to show user the list of italian football team, each record of this grid will represent a single football team and will contain all possible attributes: some fields may be empty (because, for considered team, the correspondent attribute is unknown), while the others will contain the values stored in `teams_information` table (for the considered team).
According to the above grid's field are: id, team_name and a number of fields to represent all the different attributes listed in 'attributes' table.

My question is: can I realize such a grid by using a SINGLE SQL query (maybe a proper `SELECT` query, to fetch all data I need from database tables) ? 
Can anyone suggest me how to write a similar query (if it exists) ?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Regards.

Enrico.

Comment: It's better to post DDL instead of descriptions of your tables. When you post DDL, we can load and test it locally. When you don't, we have to reverse-engineer your description. Most of us don't have time to do that.

Comment: I second that. (Imagine five or ten people reverse-engineeing the data model from the text: what a waste of time) I would personally answer this question if a usable data model+dat were provided. Now, I don't. Not that I am lazy, but because I don't want to work for lazy people.

Comment: @Catcall: he describes a fairly standard EAV model, which some of us are very familiar with.

Comment: @wildplasser: I don't think the question appears to be at all lazy. The question appears to be presented adequately and thoroughly. I think the description of the tables provided is more than adequate to answer the question.

Comment: But it is not usable without work. He could add a 20 page PDF, but it would still not be *usable*. Please post code + description + intention, not text.

Comment: @wildplasser I didn't write code here not because I'm lazy, but because I didn't have any idea on how to write a proper query to solve my issue. I'm not a professional programmer so I decided to explain my model in words.

Comment: It's OK. But for programmers (and DBA's) code is easyer to read and understand and check than text. Reading the text and constructing a working data set from it will cost me 15 minutes, constructing the query another 5. So is was not worth it. That is what @Catcall answered, but he was a bit politer than me ...

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is no, there is no simple construct in MySQL to achieve the result set you are looking for.

But it is possible to carefully (painstakingly) craft such a query. Here is an example, I trust you will be able to decipher it.  Basically, I'm using correlated subqueries in the select list, for each attribute I want returned.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , t.nickname

     , ( SELECT v1.attribute_value 
           FROM team_information v1 
           JOIN attributes a1
             ON a1.id = v1.attribute_id AND a1.attribute_name = 'city'
          WHERE v1.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1
       ) AS city

     , ( SELECT v2.attribute_value
           FROM team_information v2 JOIN attributes a2
             ON a2.id = v2.attribute_id AND a2.attribute_name = 'captain'
          WHERE v2.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1
       ) AS captain

     , ( SELECT v3.attribute_value
           FROM team_information v3 JOIN attributes a3
             ON a3.id = v3.attribute_id AND a3.attribute_name = 'f_number'
          WHERE v3.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1
       ) AS f_number

  FROM teams t
 ORDER BY t.id
```

For 'multi-valued' attributes, you'd have to pull each instance of the attribute separately.  (Use the LIMIT to specify whether you are retrieving the first one, the second one, etc.)

```
     , ( SELECT v4.attribute_value
           FROM team_information v4 JOIN attributes a4
             ON a4.id = v4.attribute_id AND a4.attribute_name = 'nickname'
          WHERE v4.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 0,1
       ) AS nickname_1st

     , ( SELECT v5.attribute_value
           FROM team_information v5 JOIN attributes a5
             ON a5.id = v5.attribute_id AND a5.attribute_name = 'nickname'
          WHERE v5.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS nickname_2nd

     , ( SELECT v6.attribute_value
           FROM team_information v6 JOIN attributes a6
             ON a6.id = v6.attribute_id AND a6.attribute_name = 'nickname'
          WHERE v6.team_id = t.id ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 2,1
       ) AS nickname_3rd
```

---

I use nickname as an example here, because American soccer clubs frequently have more than one nickname, e.g. Chicago Fire Soccer Club has nicknames: 'The Fire', 'La Máquina Roja', 'Men in Red', 'CF97', et al.)

NOT AN ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION, BUT ...

Have I mentioned numerous times before, how much I dislike working with EAV database implementations? What should IMO be a very simple query turns into an overly complicated beast of a potentially light dimming query.

Wouldn't it be much simpler to create a table where each "attribute" is a separate column? Then queries to return reasonable result sets would look more reasonable...

```
SELECT id, name, nickname, city, captain, f_number, ... FROM team
```

But what really makes me shudder is the prospect that some developer is going to decide that the LDQ should be "hidden" in the database as a view, to enable the "simpler" query.

If you go this route, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE resist any urge you may have to store this query in the database as a view.

Comment: These appear to be attributes that a little due diligence would have determined were needed ahead of time. EAV tables to save developers from having to figure out what data they should be storing are evil. Now sometimes it is not possible to know in advance (think storing medical tests where each new test might have new attributes). In that case EAV is appropriate if difficult to properly query and difficult to enforce good data integrity.

Comment: @HLGEM: yes, I agree, EAV is a workable (and sometimes appropriate) model for a database. What grieves me is the SQL contortions that we sometimes go through to transform the EAV model back into a relational presentation.  You are quite right about difficulties with enforcing data integrity and with creating queries that return correct results. The manipulation of data in an EAV database can be complex. When we present the relational view of the EAV data, then users want to INSERT or UPDATE the rows in the relational view.

Comment: Eurgh, EAV... Too bad this isn't something with CTEs, which would have allowed you to pre-join the `attribute` table to the `team_information` table (for the name column).

Comment: @X-Zero: Yes, but MySQL does not support CTEs.

Comment: Thank you very much spencer7593 :-) Your answer is very clear and the code you attached has been very useful. About EAV model I agree with you, actually the query you suggested me is a bit complicated (I have worked as a programmer for two months, this is the first time I use subqueries in select list). I decided to use that model because I need to build a flexible database, where I can decide to add a new attribute at any time, without having too many complications to do this (such as perform great changes to php code to fetch data).

Comment: @EnricoMassone - ... And how are you going to tell your PHP pages which new attributes to fetch?  Most of the time, specific pages/modules only care about specific attributes.  If you specify which columns a page is interested in the various `SELECT` statements (ie, don't use `SELECT *`), you can add attributes at any time.  Then you only have to changes those pages that care about the new attributes - which you'd have to do anyways.  Getting _all_ the attributes _all_ the time is likely counterproductive.

Comment: I want to keep voting your answer up.  Great call with the EAV and View issues that are bound to arise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a slightly different route.  Spencer's answer is fantastic, and it addresses the issue quite well, but there's still a large underlying problem.

The data that you are trying to display on the site is over-normalized in the database.  I won't elaborate, since, again, Spencer's answer highlights the issue pretty well.

Rather, I'd like to recommend a solution that denormalizes the data a bit.

Convert all of your Team data into a single table with many columns.  (If there is Player data that isn't covered in the question, that would be a second table, but I'll gloss over that for now.)

Sure, you'll have a *whole* bunch of columns, and a lot of the columns might be NULL for a lot of the rows.  It's not normalized, and it's not pretty, but here's the huge advantage that you gain.

Your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM Teams
```

That's it.  That gets displayed right to the website and you are done.  You might have to go out of your way to realize this schema, but it would be totally worth the time investment.

Comment: I also favor the traditional relational database model, with one row representing an instance of an "entity", with attribute values stored in named columns. Tables in this scheme are familiar to many users, compatible with what a lot of users do in Excel, for example, and also using a child tables for repeating attributes. But data stored in a EAV model is also workable, and even appropriate sometimes, even if it is somewhat cumbersome. An EAV model really does require another layer of logic, for both retrieval from the database, and especially for manipulation of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you want the rows in the attributes table to appear as columns in the result recordset. If this is correct, then then in SQL you would use PIVOT.
A quick search on SO seems to indicate that there is no PIVOT equivalent in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple PHP script to generalize spencer's idea to solve my issue.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/db.config.php'); //this file performs connection to mysql

/*
 * Following function requires a table name ($table)
 * and a number of service fields ($num). Given those parameters
 * it returns the number of table fields (excluding service fields). 
 */

function get_fields_number($table,$num,$conn)
{   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    return mysql_num_fields($result)-$num; //remember there are $num service fields
}

/*
 * Following function requires a table name ($table) and an array
 * containing a list of service fields names. Given those parameters, 
 * it returns the list of field names. That list is contained within an array and
 * service fields are excluded.
 */

function get_fields_name($table,$service,$conn)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    $name = array(); //Array to be returned
    for ($i=0;$i<mysql_num_fields($result);$i++)
    {
        if(!in_array(mysql_field_name($result,$i),$service))
    {
       //currently selected field is not a service field
       $name[] = mysql_field_name($result,$i); 
    }
    }
    return $name;
}

//Below $conn is db connection created in 'db.config.php'

$query = "SELECT `name` FROM  `detail_arg` WHERE visibility = 0";
$res = mysql_query($query,$conn);
if($res===false)
{
    $err_msg = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_error($conn));
    echo "{success:false,data:'".$err_msg."'}";
    die();
}
$arg = array(); //list of argument names
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $arg[] = $row['name'];
}

//Following function writes the select subquery which is
    //necessary to build a column containing a single attribute.

function make_subquery($attribute) //$attribute contains attribute name
{
    $query = "";
    $query.="(SELECT incident_detail.arg_value ";
    $query.="FROM incident_detail ";
    $query.="INNER JOIN detail_arg ";
    $query.="ON incident_detail.arg_id = detail_arg.id AND      detail_arg.name='".$attribute."' ";
    $query.="WHERE incident.id = incident_detail.incident_id) ";
    $query.="AS $attribute";
    return $query;
}

/*

echo make_subquery("date"); //debug code

*/

$subquery = array(); //list of subqueries
for($i=0;$i<count($arg);$i++)
{
    $subquery[] = make_subquery($arg[$i]); 
}

$query = "SELECT "; //final query containing subqueries

$fields = get_fields_name("incident",array("id","visibility"),$conn); 
    //list of 'incident' table's fields

for($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++)
{
    $query.="incident.".$fields[$i].", ";
}

//insert the subqueries

$sub = implode($subquery,", ");
$query .= $sub;

    $query.=" FROM incident ORDER BY incident.id";
echo $query;
?>
```